# Understanding of filter method

Tags: javascript, filter, parameters

Guys Im pretty stuck understanding the code here. What I cant get is the parameters of filter method and Ive searched alot but I cant get what they says. I also cant get the line of code here (arr[index+1] += 'extra'). Can someone explain it to me. Im a beginner and I will appreciate every help of yours. #javascript

// Modifying each words

```
let words = ['spray', 'limit', 
'exuberant', 
'destruction','elite', 'present']

const modifiedWords = 
words.filter( (word, index, arr) 
=> {
  arr[index+1] +=' extra' // my prob
  return word.length < 6
})
```

Comment: Are you filtering the string with the length more then 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const modifiedWords = 
words.filter( (word, index, arr)=> {
  arr[index+1] +=' extra' //Line 1
  return word.length < 6 // Line 2
})
```

Line 1 = At this line, its appending ' extra' to its next element

Line 2 = in next iteration word length ll be greater than 6 so this condition ll return false

therefore it ll always return first element if it is less than 6 characters

so you words array will after this filter

```
[
  "spray",
  "limit extra",
  "exuberant extra",
  "destruction extra",
  "elite extra",
  "present extra",
  "undefined extra" //its 'undefined extra'bcz on last index it ll apend' extra' to next index
]
```

Comment: Thats not the output sir. Its from mdn example. But I think of that too. Mdn says because its modified.